# jrat - java profiling fails

Tags: java, profiler

I run:

```
~/dan/java/hello $ java -javaagent:shiftone-jrat.jar -cp '..' hello.hello
```

and get (within longer trace output):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 35 in method hello.hello.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V at offset 14
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:488)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:480)
```

Went with jrat because it seemed turnkey.  I'm open to suggestions for other turn-key, command-line Linux-compatible profilers.  Just need to know very simple info i.e. what functions my program is spending most of its time in, in the meantime I'll <s>poke around with other profilers suggested here and there</s> add lots of print statements until I realize my regexes are fine and my stream -> string conversion is taking forever.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using JDK6 or JDK7. JDK7 added more restrictive checks for stackmap frames and they can result in such errors when the bytecode is modified by tools unaware of the changes in JDK7 verifier (older versions of ASM eg.)

Comment: Use JDK6. It seems that jRat hasn't been updated for a while so it is not adjusted for these changes. Or use another profiling tool that can deal with the new JDK7 restrictions.